# Help coding small website HTML

Tags: html, css

I have created a small PSD Mockup of a about page for my website. However I have no idea how to code HTML and CSS.

I currently have the following code:

index.html

```
<html>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="css.css"
type="text/css">
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<div id=body>
</div>
<div id=header>
<h3><font title=Futura>Header</font></h3>
</div>
</body>
```

css.css

```
body {
  background-image: url("background.png");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
header {
    background-image: url("otherBackground.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I would like to have the background image of body to have the background image of header on top of it and then some text ontop of that.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: First, find a good HTML/CSS tutorial. Try: http://htmldog.com/

Comment: You'll also be amazed at how much you can learn simply by running your HTML through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fixing any flagged issues.

Comment: And stay away from the w3schools if you really want to learn properly!

Comment: Do not use the <font> tag. Style the <h3> tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you'll want to utilize nesting and begin to understand general document flow. You are able and encouraged to place HTML elements inside of other HTML elements to establish a parent::child flow and control the position of the elements on your page. Notice how I moved the `header` element inside of the `body` div

```
<html>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css.css"
type="text/css">
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<div id="header">
<h3><font title="Futura">Header</font></h3>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

You also need to make sure you surround your element attributes with quotation marks. In your css, if you are targeting a div, you need to specify that by prefixing a `#` to the element name.

Not a bad start, but keep reading tutorials - you'll get the hang of it!

Comment: can I now center the otherBackground inside the body div?

Comment: absolutely - you should probably check out some of the other sites that these guys are recommending to learn a little more about the basics!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the # before "header"

```
#header { }
```

Comment: thanks, but I now just get a small amount of the otherBackground showing

Comment: Give the #header div a height and width, same as the otherBackground image.